# How to import a phylogenetic tree (in nexus format) with node support values in R

Tags: r, phylogeny, ggtree

I have a phylogenetic tree in nexus format that was generated with RAxML. In the tree file, there are node support values. I want to plot this tree in R with the support values showing. However, when I import the tree file in R with the read.nexus function in ape, the node values do not appear in $node.labels. Can someone recommend another option in R?

Comment: RAxML, or raxml-ng? The former has both a bipartitionsBranchLabels file with a weird support formatting in the newick, where the support values are wrapped in square brackets ([ ]) and a bipartitions file, where they are normally formatted.

Comment: See page 49 of the [RAxML v8.2.X manual](https://cme.h-its.org/exelixis/resource/download/NewManual.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this tutorial about ggtree. You will find the solution.
[https://guangchuangyu.github.io/ggtree-book/short-introduction-to-r.html][ggtree]